# How can I display Blurred Image just like WhatsApp Profile Picture?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-imageview, android-glide

How can I display a Blurry image when it is not fully retrieved from the server/api?
I just want to do the same as like WhatsApp profile picture i.e display raw image of the original one until the real image not getting loaded.

Answer (score 2):

You can set thumbnail until the original image is being loaded.
Thumbnail is basically a low quality and small image so it loaded instantly.
Glide provides a easier was of doing this.

Code

```
 val thumbnailRequest = Glide.with(this)
     .load("https://picsum.photos/50/50?image=0")

Glide.with(this)
        .load("https://picsum.photos/2000/2000?image=0")
        .thumbnail(thumbnailRequest)
        .into(imageThumbnail)
```

Comment: Thumbnail will work fine but it should use another image which ned another image with less quality but what if i have only one Image in my API response?

Comment: You need to update response two return images , one full and one for full quality. If you are uploading images from app end , you can upload 2 images one low quality and and one full and server return accordingly. 
If you only want blur loading effect, you can download full image and blur it for few seconds before showing actual image

Answer (score 1):

Scale the image down to a very small size like say 8x8 pixels. Send that data to the client for placeholder when you start downloading . It should not be more than 4 * 8 * 8 = 256 B or 0.25 KB in size, so sending it to the client will not be a problem no matter how slow the client's connection speed is. When the download is finish you can change to original image.